# Programmatically Open Link in WebView

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview

I have an NS Window with a WebView.

My program takes in a search query and executes a Google search with it, the results being displayed in the WebView, like a browser.

Instead of displaying the search results in the WebView, I'd like to automatically open the first link and display the contents of that result instead.

As a better example, how do I display the contents of the first result of Google in a WebView?

Is this even possible?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the direct Google Search API. That would be more convinient. 
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list?hl=de-DE

Also you could also try to make a google request like the "I'm feeling lucky" button, which will direct you automatically to the first search result.

If you have to parse the HTML, you need to have a look at the HTML structure of the google result page. Look for specific `id` and `class` css properties in the `div` and `a` tags. If you found the ones, where the actual results are you can start parsing that content. Also i guess it would be easier to put some javascript together, that will find the first result and open it. (More easier than parsing the HTML using obj-c). You can evaluate javascript in the webview using `[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"put your js code here"]`.

Comment: thanks very much for the great answer, the google API is resulting in an error when I try it so I'll go for the JavaScript way. I've looked at how Google displays results, and have found the div, with class and id where I want to get the information. Now I just need to find out how to get that with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Comment: I know how javascript works, i was a web dev before this, I meant I don't know how to combine the javascript with cocoa and objective-c :)

Comment: just put it as string in the call, where i wrote "put your js code here" :).

Comment: ok i've done exactly that and it works! thank you SO much!! now i just need to extract the content of a specific tag, if you know how to help i've asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302347/extract-contents-of-anchor-tag. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

The first way to accomplish that that goes through my head is to **parse** the HTML response from Google, then launch a WebView with the first link you extracted.

Take a look at **regular expressions** to make it easy.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is what I had in mind as well, but I was hoping for a little more help. I can't find anything about parsing HTML responses in Cocoa or how to use REGEX on it, any ideas?

Comment: Search a bit more because I won't explain regular expressions here I'm afraid. Plus I don't know how to accomplish that in Cocoa. Edit your first post and wait for a Cocoa developer. Good luck

Comment: You can use NSRegularExpression or for older than 10.7 take a look at NSPredicate.